# Webmock to return an Response Object from an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webmock

I call out to an API, where I then take their xml and parse it to return a `Response` object.

Typical stuff for calling a 3rd party API.

So now in my tests I want to use webmock  to say "When you get a request to go to example.com, just give me a Response.new object so i can continue on with my code and process it`.

I am using rspec.  Here is the code thus far.

Test code is:

```
stub_request(:any, /.*blah.*/).
  with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
  to_return(:status => 200, 
            :body => "#{BlahResponse.new("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><data><type><![CDATA[success]]></type><subject><![CDATA[Info]]></subject><code>29</code><description><![CDATA[Success]]></description><meeting_id><![CDATA[awesome-455]]></meeting_id></data>")}",
            :headers => {})
```

The error always results in response is not a method of Nil, meaning I am not passing anything it looks like.

Comment: Won't you be creating the Response object in the API code when you make the request? It doesn't make sense to stub a request to a URL to return an object, because that can't actually happen. In your code you would be taking the status, body and headers and assigning them to a new Request object, no?

Comment: Yes.  I tried stuff that XML in there, but it's not parsing like my. Normal code does. Shall I rephrase question to say how do I return XML properly?

Comment: Hmm... then you should post the code where you're parsing the XML. The stub will just pass on whatever you put in there.

Comment: everything in the quotes between .new(" and ") i put in the response in quotes... ugh.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is this still a problem? If so it would help if you could post the code where you make the request. This shouldn't be hard to fix.

Comment: the problem was PEBKAC in a way for this question.  in the `to_return` instead of just `:status => 200` i should have put `:status => [200, "OK"]`